# How to deploy mono ASP.NET MVC application to xsp?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, xsp

I have a very simple asp.net mvc application that runs on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ during debug (as expected).

I am trying to export this application so everyone on my LAN can access it, which means I must deploy the application and run it on a web server. Thus, I have decided to run the application using xsp (I believe to be the easiest option).

I have xsp installed and my application works, I just don't know how to deploy it and run it with xsp.

I wonder if there is a guide that explains how to deploy and run the mvc application with xsp (I have been searching without success for one) or if someone could please explain me how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a *nix box?

If so, you can simply switch in to the directory and run xsp4, e.g.

```
$ cd /path/to/my/asp/web/site/root
$ xsp4 --nonstop
```

You can run it on a different port using the port switch, e.g.:

```
$ xsp4 --nonstop --port=80
```